# How to load commits in a certain date range with fugitive?

Tags: git, plugin-fugitive

I am able to do 
`git log --pretty=format:"%h" --after="2018-06-7" --until="2018-06-10"`, in the shell, but if I try to do it in vim with fugitive like this: `:Glog --after="2018-6-7" --until="2018-06-10" --` nothing happens (the quickfix window is empty).  Am I passing the parameters incorrectly or is this not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the quotes in your command.  The double quote character is the start of a comment in vimscript.  See [`help :comment`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#:comment).
So you should use `:Glog --after=2018-6-7 --until=2018-6-10` instead.

For the future: If you need to give a quoted string to a vim command you can try `'` instead of `"` that might work better in general.